# javascript to read file selects a file but doesn't read it

Tags: javascript

My script selects a file... but doesn't read it. I've been banging my head on it but can't make it work. It's part of my studies, I'm a greenhorn and I'm lost.

```
function readBlob() {
    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;

      var file = files[0];
      var start = 0;
      var stop = file.size;
      var reader = new FileReader();

      if (file.webkitSlice) {
        var blob = file.webkitSlice(start, stop);
        //Creates new blob if using google chrome
      } else if (file.mozSlice) {
         var blob = file.mozSlice(start, stop);
         //Creates new blob if using mozilla firefox
      }

      //read the contents of the file in as text into the blob
      reader.readAsText(blob); 

      reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
           document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = 
               evt.target.result;
        }
      };
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of slicing to make a blob? By default, a file is a type of blob, making what you did unnecessary. I don't think that will fix the problem, but give it a try.

Comment: No, it didn't work. The funny thing is I'm following my lecturer's prompts to build the script.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect - your current sample does not do anything when `files.length` is not 0... Maybe some copy-paste error but there was no extra curly braces when I removed extra whitespace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple syntax error to me, but maybe just an error inserting it into stack overflow. The entire thing, the slicing of the file, the insertion into the document, everything, is inside of the `if (!files.length)` statement. Therefore, the script only executes when there is no file (catching on to the problem yet :) but it is actually meant to do the opposite. All of the important stuff is supposed to be outside of the if statement.